# Python Django - Not 'object' attribute on scaffolded model

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm only a newbie in Python and Django.
I'm working with a MySQL database, I have created the model with the command: `python manage.py inspectdb > /app/models/model.py`. And it works wonderfully.

**model.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals    
from django.db import models


class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    login = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    forum_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    hwid = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    use_allowed_hwids = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    social_id = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    securitycode = models.CharField(max_length=192, blank=True, null=True)
    newsletter = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    empire = models.IntegerField()
    name_checked = models.IntegerField()
    availdt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='availDt', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    mileage = models.IntegerField()
    cash = models.IntegerField()
    gold_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    silver_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    safebox_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    autoloot_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    fish_mind_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    marriage_fast_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    money_drop_rate_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    shop_double_up_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    total_cash = models.IntegerField()
    total_mileage = models.IntegerField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_pw_change = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    web_admin = models.IntegerField()
    web_ip = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    web_aktiviert = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    question1 = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    answer1 = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    last_vote = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    lostpw_token = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    last_play = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    remember_token = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account'
```

All works fine, but I can't see any "objects" attribute in my intellisense, and if i write it i can see only "Accounts.objects"... And no more
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUlZ5.png)

I'm using Python 36

Comment: This isn't a question about models at all, but about your editor. What editor is it? Does it know about Django? There is some tricky metaclass magic underlying models, so IDEs don't often know about all the attributes; however, this doesn't actually affect your code. The IDE might have a Django plug-in though.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 . I've tried also with Visual Studio Code, but nothing... I can't see any "objects" attribute